# on-yomi and kun-yomi readings for the one compound?

Tags: meaning

Are there examples of kanji compounds that have recognised on-yomi and kun-yomi readings for the one compound? Does the meaning vary depending on which reading is chosen?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66506/is-%e5%b9%b4%e6%9c%88-months-and-years-read-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d-or-%e3%81%ad%e3%82%93%e3%81%92%e3%81%a4-and-is-there-a-difference/66516#66516

Comment: Please clarify: are you talking about things like 今日【きょう】 vs. 今日【こんにち】?

Comment: On the other hand, there's 日日: ひび and にちにち mean the same, but ひにち doesn't :)